"Pregeometry" on $\mathbb{F}_p$-Algebras
For a field $K$ of characteristic $p>0$, the operator $\text{cl}_K(A):=K^p(A)$ defines a pregeometry on $K$:

The conditions $A\subseteq\text{cl}_K(A)$, finiteness $\text{cl}_K(A)=\bigcup_{A_0\subseteq_\text{fin}A}\text{cl}(A_0)$, $\text{cl}_K(\text{cl}_K(A))=\text{cl}_K(A)$ are clear.
The exchange property: assume that $a\in \text{cl}_K(A\cup\{b\})\backslash\text{cl}_K(A)$, then $K^p(A\cup\{a\})/K^p(A)$ is of degree $p$. Since $a\in\text{cl}_K(A\cup\{b\})$, $K^p(A\cup\{b\})/K^p(A)$ is of degree $p$. Then $K^p(A\cup\{a\})\subseteq K^p(A\cup\{b\})$ implies equality by the reason of degree.

Does $\text{cl}_R(A):=R^p[A]$ (the $R^p$-algebra generated by $A$) also define a pregeometry when $R$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra?
Update: There is one thing I want to mention after Alex Kruckman's answer. It is actually possible to define the notion $p$-independence and $p$-basis through the definition of $\text{cl}_R(A)$. It is true that for a domain $R$, a $p$-basis of $R$ remains a $p$-basis in $\text{Frac}(R)$, so even if exchange fails, the cardinality of $p$-basis of $R$ is fixed.

What do you mean by $K^p(A)$? It looks like $A$ is a subset of $K$. Does $K^p(A)$ mean ${ k^p a : k \in K, a \in A }$?

@QiaochuYuan I think it is the field generated by $K^p$ and $A$? If $A$ is finite, since elements in $A$ are algebraic over $K^p$, the $K^p$-algebra generated by $A$ is a field. If $A$ is infinite, $K^p(A)$ should also be a field.

To answer @QiaochuYuan's question definitively: Here $K^p$ (resp. $R^p$) is notation for the set of $p^{th}$ powers in $K$ (resp. $R$), i.e., the image of the Frobenius endomorphism. Then $K^p(A)$ is standard notation for "subfield generated by". But in the case of "subalgebra generated by", the standard notation would be $R^p[A]$, since $R^p(A)$ suggests the elements of $A$ should have multiplicative inverses. You should edit the question to clarify, RoastedFish.

Assuming I understand the notation correctly (as in my comment to the OP above), the answer is no, because exchange can fail. In fact, it fails in the simplest nontrivial example. $\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}$
Let $R=\mathbb{F}_p[t]$, the polynomial ring in one variable over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then $R^p=\mathbb{F}_p[t^p]$.
We have $t^{p+1}\in \cl(t)\setminus \cl(\varnothing)=R\setminus R^p$, but $t\notin \cl(t^{p+1})=\mathbb{F}_p[t^p,t^{p+1}]$.
There's nothing special about $p+1$ here: any $k>1$ which is relatively prime to $p$ works.
